# To what extent would a 21st Century Industrial power collapse under an airborne HIV-like virus?

Tags: post-apocalypse, apocalypse, modern-age, diseases, dystopia

In an alternate 21st Century Earth, an airborne strain of HIV, or a brand new airborne virus that causes the same symptoms of HIV evolves. The new Super-HIV virus retains the ability to transmit by bodily fluids and from mother to child, but can also spread through aerosols (coughing, sneezing), as in nCoV or influenza.

The symptoms and mechanism of action of the virus remains largely the same. Asymptomatic latency period is measured in years or even decades, and infection causes chronic immunosuppression leading to death by opportunistic infections. Similar to real life HIV, infection can be managed by drugs but never cured.

Let us assume that the plague is released on a wealthy and largely stable (at day zero) capitalist industrial society, but with low transparency and moderate amounts of corruption. The upper and middle classes make up for a relatively small amount of the population. While the vast majority of the lower class have their basic needs met (i.e. Low quality housing and basic amounts of food and water), there is an significant income between the upper/middle and the lower classes.

Exposure to HIV is low and most medical staff are unfamiliar with signs and symptoms. The technological and industrial base to manufacture retroviral exist but since the virus is brand new there is little production capability on Day Zero. The medical system has limited government sponsorship for minor treatments but leaves most chronic illnesses uncovered.

Could the plague potentially cause the entire human population to be infected and lead to a dystopia where almost all humans have drastically reduced lifespan unless they have access to drugs?

EDIT: added brief on society. Rephrased question to be less broad. Extraneous questions removed

Comment: Speculative questions of the type "What would happen if..." are universally too broad for this Stack.

Comment: A much narrower form of this question might be "to what extent would society collapse". You'll get the same answers, but it's much more focused than "what would happen"

Answer (score 8):

The average life expectancy of someone with HIV today is about 70 years.  This is only slightly less than normal and still much longer than "healthy" people throughout most of human history.  This is to say that civilization would be fine in the greater scheme of things.

If this is a true capitalist society, then economy of scale will kick in fairly quickly.  If this is a regulated capitalist society and a major pharmaceutical company tries hiding behind patent and prescription laws to charge ridiculous prices for the medication, then there is generally going to already be something in place such as Section 1498 which allows the government to declare eminent domain on the patented product and begin producing the generic at fair cost.

As for production capacity, HIV takes 10+ years to kill.  This is plenty of time for a large pharmaceutical company to ramp up to meet a major global distribution need.

The most likely outcome would be that immunoboosters would just become a part of daily life for future generations much like how we just accept that the cost of owning a vehicle is a part of life that was not true 100 or so years ago. There may be some initial panic with medicine shortages, but within a few years, production would match up to consumer demands and they would just become an over the counter medication right there between your toothbrushes and cough drops.

The medicine will probably become a form of leverage in places that are already lawless cartel ruled sorts of places, but in that case it's not so much making civilization collapse as intensifying where it already has.

Comment: Well, one thing you *can* say is, "big pharma would get richer". +1

Comment: Dang, I was gonna post that but you beat me to it by 4 minutes. I think this is especially true because the OP's assumption: `Exposure to HIV is low and most medical staff are unfamiliar with signs and symptoms.` is already untrue; society is equipped to deal with HIV, just not on a large scale (yet).

Comment: Wasn't this the plot of a Mission Impossible movie?

Comment: A LOT of people will die from an airborn hiv before the medicine's production ramp up.

Comment: @Geronimo Maybe, maybe not.  HIV takes a 10+ years to kill even without medication. The R&D part of developing a new medicine is the hard part.  Once a pharma company knows how, mass producing medicine within that time frame is not so hard.  Especially when you consider how many investors will be willing to throw money at this particular problem.  More remote parts of the world will not get the access as quickly as developed nations, but places that see less travel also take longer for airborne diseases to spread to them.